# How to evaluate an expression built out of an ADT

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Here's my ADT:

```
data Ex a = I Integer  --integer
           | Add (Ex a) (Ex a) --add 
           | Variable a --variable
           | Def [(a, Ex a)] (Ex a) --defining local variables
```

And here's my evaluate function:

```
eval :: Ex a -> Integer
eval (I n) = n
eval (Add e1 e2) = eval e1 + eval e2
```

How do I continue `eval` for `Variable` and `Def`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some more hints to help you write the solution yourself.

Some suggestions

- You need to perform `lookup` on the list of type `[(a,Ex a)]` and hence need `Eq a` constraint on that.
- Your evaluation can fail if you have not defined a local variable and used it. In that case the `eval` function should return `Nothing` otherwise `Just answer`.
- I have written most part of your code the only place you need to write is for `Variable a` case. Which is very simple as you just need to `lookup` a in `xs` and return the value after evaluating it if `lookup` succeeds else `Nothing`.

The code becomes

```
eval :: Eq a => Ex a -> Maybe Integer
eval = eval' []
  where eval' :: Eq a => [(a, Ex a)] -> Ex a -> Maybe Integer
        eval' _ (I n) = Just n
        eval' xs (Add e1 e2) = liftA2 (+) (eval' xs e1) (eval' xs e2) -- liftA2 from Control.Applicative
        eval' xs (Variable a) = -- write your code here
        eval' xs (Def ys e) = eval' (ys ++ xs) e -- Think of the order in which you want to combine two binding if same named variable is present in both xs and ys.
```

Comment: it will give (Just 8). You just need to write correct definition for `Variable a` case after reading point 3 of my suggestions.

Comment: Thank you so much. this is what I cam up with:eval(fromJust (lookup a xs)). Is it possible for you to give me your gmail or yahoo ID?

Comment: You should not use fromJust, It will give runtime error if lookup fails. You can use something like `eval' xs =<< lookup a xs`

Comment: Thank you. It is required to add type     Ex String    for showing  expression, should I add it to datatype or there is another way?

Comment: @Sam Just add `deriving Show` at the end of the datatype definition.

Comment: But the question asks to use type Ex String to present expression?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18289/discussion-between-sam-and-satvik)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint:

```
eval :: Ex a -> Integer
eval = eval' []
  where eval' :: [(a, Integer)] -> Ex a -> Integer
        eval' _ (I n) = n
        -- etc
```

Comment: thank you for the hint. But local variable is defined as:    Def ["x", I 10] (Add (Variable "x") 2), and when evaluating it, it should print out 12.